# how to print only duplicate numbers in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to print only duplicate numbers in  a list and need to multiply by count. the code is as follows , the output should be ,

{1:3, 2:2, 3:2} need to multiply each numbers by count and print as separate answers:

```
answer1 = 1*3, answer2 = 2*2 , answer3 = 3*2
```

Current attempt:

```
    from collections import Counter

    alist = [1,2,3,5,1,2,1,3,1,2]
    a = dict(Counter(a_list))

    print(a)
```

Comment: then iterate through `a` and do the rest of the job.

Comment: there are 4 occurrences of 1, not 3 BTW

Comment: Please continue your attempt. No reason to stop halfway.

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` already does the heavy lifting. So for the rest, what about generating a list of the values occuring more than once, formatting the output as you wish ? (sorting the keys seems necessary so indexes match the keys order):

```
from collections import Counter

a_list = [1,2,3,5,1,2,1,3,1,2]
a = ["{}*{}".format(k,v) for k,v in sorted(Counter(a_list).items()) if v > 1]

print(a)
```

result:

```
['1*4', '2*3', '3*2']
```

If you want the numerical result instead:

```
a = [k*v for k,v in sorted(Counter(a_list).items()) if v > 1]
```

result (probably more useful):

```
[4, 6, 6]
```

Assigning to separate variables (`answer1,answer2,answer3 = a`) is not a very good idea. Keep a indexed `list`

Comment: thanks it was really helpful how can I get the answer i mean as index 1 answer should be 6. how can i recall them for separate answers as 4 , 6 , 6 ? please help me out

Comment: a = [k*v for k,v in sorted(Counter(a_list).items()) if v > 1] [4, 6, 6] hi how can i get the total of multiply numbers as 16 please advice me thanks

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre ,basically i print randint 1-6 to the list and check the values occuring more than once. then it should multiply by each numbers count and get the total. when i run next randint the list should deduct current count here its 3 and only print 3 random numbers 1-6. please advice